# Compact Function Set

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

If a uniformly equicontinuous family of functions is analytic on an open disk in the complex plane, it has compact closure by Montel's theorem (and Arzela-Ascoli). Is it possible that this set *is* compact by showing it to be complete and totally bounded? Do uniformly convergent sequences of uniformly equicontinuous functions in the complex plane (on an open disk) converge to a uniformly continuous, analytic function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can answer my own question.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a uniformly equiconinuous set of functions, analytic on some $G\subseteq \mathbb C$. By Montel's theorem, we have that $\overline{\mathcal F}$ is compact. We show that $\mathcal F=\overline{\mathcal F}$ by demonstrating that $\mathcal F$ contains its limit points. Let $\{f_n\}\subseteq\mathcal F$ be a sequence of functions such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise, and $f_n\neq f$ for all $n$. Consider any closed loop $D\in G$. Since $D$ is compact, the convergence on $D$ is uniform. Therefore $f$ is continuous. Furthermore, we may apply the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem,

$$\int_D f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_D f_n=0$$

Since this is true for every closed path $D$, $f$ is analytic on $G$ by Morera's Theorem.